# asp.net web api 2 identity - suppress migration in production

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api2

Can we suppress migration scripts running for asp.net web api 2 **identity management**. Is there an option where we check for migration only during deployment and suppress the same for the rest of the executions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To disable migrations you need to set database initialiser to be null:

```
Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(null)
```

And I think it is a good practice to separate deployment and application running for permission reasons. Usually database user permissions to run an application only require read and write. Rarely that user needs to do modify the database.

And migrations usually change the DB, so extra permissions are required. So it is logical to make migrations only on deployment stage and outwith the application.